# how to update a computed result of several columns in one record into postgresql database with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, delayed-job

I have a table called "Scores" which has 4 columns, "first", "second", "third", and "average" for keeping record of user's score.

When a user create the record initially, he can leave "average" column blank. Then he can edit all 3 scores later.

After editing, the user can see the computed average (or sum, or any calculation result.) in his show page, since I have

def show
  @ave = (@score.first + @score.second + @score.third)/3
end

However, @ave is not in the database, how can I update @ave into the column of "average" of my database?

1. Ideally, it would be the best if the computing takes place before updating into database, so all 4 values can be updated into database together. It might have something to do with Active Record Callbacks, but I don't know how to do that.
2. Second approach, I think i need a "trigger" in database so that it can compute and update "average" column as soon as other 3 columns got updated. If this is how you do it, please let me know and the advantage of comparing with solution number 1.
3. Last approach, since the user already know the average in his show page, I don't have to update the computed average into "average" column immediately. I think i can leave this to a delayed_job or background job. If this is how you do it, please let know me how.

Thank you in advance!(ruby 2.3, rails 5.0.1, postgresql 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really do need the average stored in the database for some reason, I would add an attribute to the Score model:

```
def average
  (first + second + third)/3.0
end
```

If one or more might not be present, I would:

```
def average
  actual_scores = [first, second, third].compact
  return nil if actual_scores.empty?
  actual_scores.sum / actual_scores.size
end
```

If you do need the average saved, then I would add a before_validate callback:

```
before_validation do
  self.average = (first + second + third)/3.0
end
```

Comment: I used before_save instead. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ideas 1 and 2 are perfectly valid approaches. Idea 3 is overkill and I would strongly recommend against that approach.

In idea 1, all you need to do (in any language) is simply look at each individual value put in (not including average) and generate the average value to be included in your insert statement. It's really as simple as that.

Idea 2 requires making a trigger as follows:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_average()
   RETURNS trigger AS
 $BODY$
 BEGIN
  NEW.AVERAGE=(NEW.first+NEW.second+NEW.third)/3;
  RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $BODY$
```

Then assign it to run on update or insert of your table:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER last_name_changes
   BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE
   ON scores
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_average();
```

Comment: I am sorry that I only can make one answer as the correct answer! You have proved that the database trigger approach would work too. Thanks a lot!